# Multivariable calculas

Tags: integration, matrices, multivariable-calculus

Let $f\colon \mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^n$ be a continuous function such that $ \int_{\mathbb R^n} |f(x)|dx<\infty$. let $A$ be a real $n\times n$ invertible matrix and for $x,y\in\mathbb R^n$, let $\langle x,y\rangle$ denote standard inner product in $ R^n$. Then show
$$ 
\int_{\mathbb R^n} f(Ax)e^{i\langle y,x\rangle}dx = \int_{\mathbb R^n} f(x)e^{i\langle (A^{-1})^{T}y,x\rangle }\frac {dx}{|\det A|}.
$$ 
Any help with explanation will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This follows from [the substitution for multiple variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution): we use the map $\varphi\colon x\mapsto  Ax$, for which the Jacobian is not hard to compute.